# react native: uncheck of checkbox doesn't works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I really want to know how I can change my sample code so that it is possible to uncheck the checkbox?
At the moment I can only check but cant uncheck and I really do not understand where the problem is.
I would be happy for some help with show me how to change my code for the desired result .

```
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';
import { useRoute, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const ActionsScreen = () => {
  const route = useRoute<ActionScreenRouteProp>();
  const params = route.params;
  const { actionList, eventType, emergencyRole } = params
  const [checkList, setCheckList] = useState<any[]>(actionList.map(e => ({ key: e.key, checked: false })));
  const isChecked = (key) => {
    checkList.filter(e => e.key == key)[0].checked
  }

  const renderActionItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={index}
        activeOpacity={.7}
        style={styles.touchableOpacity}
        onPress={() => { console.log(item) }}
      >
        <CheckBox
          style={styles.checkBox}
          tintColors={{ true: 'white', false: 'white' }}
          value={isChecked(item.key)}
          onValueChange={() => {
            const newCheckList = checkList.slice()
            newCheckList.forEach(e => {
              if (e.key == item.key) {
                e.checked = !e.checked
              }
            })
            setCheckList(newCheckList)
          }}
        />
        <Text style={styles.labelText}>{`${item.sequenceID}. ${item.label}`}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

  return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          style={styles.flatListView}
          data={actionList}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={renderActionItem}
          
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please tell what npm package are you using, and what is it that you have tried.

Comment: ok, i add my code that i tried to do .
please help me to fix my code to get the desired result .